# XCode 6 UITableViewCell parameters inconsistent

Tags: ios, uitableview

For some time I have been struggling to have text fields at the same distance from the top of a table view cell. I have tried many combinations but never got it to work consistently.

For example in one TableView here are two cells:
Cell 1 - row height = 102, textview height = 86, y 8 and top space to superview is 8
Cell 2 - row height = 102, textview height = 86, y 8 and top space to superview is 0

If I force the top space in Cell 1 to 0 it wants to change y = 0 and textview height = 94

What am I doing wrong? or is this an storyboard problem?

Comment: This question is a little unclear. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: My app uses tableviews extensively. However, I can't get the text fields in the tableviewcells to position themselves at a consistent distance from the top of the cells. Some text fields are right at the top, and others are a distance (usually 8) down. The overall appearance is untidy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using constraints? Constraints help align objects and will help tackle different sizes of phones.
Might find this video helpful..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

Comment: I definitely use constraints ... I pin top and bottom to the superview.